# Selenium in Python only executing one function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, build-automation, browser-automation

I am creating automation using Selenium in Python but when I run this code it only executes the first function only correctly which is the select_filter_options('Seniority', selected_seniority) and the other functions next to it are neglected by the script. What do you think the problem of my code? Thank you!!!

```
def select_filter_options(filter_name, selected_options):
    # Find and click the filter button
    filter_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text()='{filter_name}']/ancestor::a")))
    filter_button.click()

    # Find and click the span element to open the dropdown
    span = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='rs-input-group-addon']")))
    span.click()

    # Loop through each selected option
    for option in selected_options:
        # Find and click the item label for the option
        item_label_xpath = f"//div[@class='SearchFilterFieldInput__ItemLabel-giZgoQ ifCFA' and text()='{option}']"
        item_label = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, item_label_xpath)))
        item_label.click()

# Select seniority options
select_filter_options('Seniority', selected_seniority)

# Select department options
select_filter_options('Department', selected_departments)

# Select employee size options
select_filter_options('Employee Size', selected_sizes)

# Select revenue options
select_filter_options('Revenue', selected_revenue)
```

All the functions on filters be executed properly

Comment: Is there an error message? If so, edit your question and paste the full error message as text, properly formatted. Have you tried adding a break point and walking through the code? Have you tried adding print statements to see how far it gets? It's hard to determine the problem with the limited information you've provided.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.